# CSS Apply filters (svg) to DIV in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, filter

The idea come from : http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeGooeyEffects/

Every things works well offline.
But when i put on my server, or works with Wamp. My DIV element just disapear completly on Firefox ??

Code HTML index.html

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800">
      <defs>
        <filter id="goo">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="12" result="blur" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 35 -15" result="goo" />
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

Code CSS

```
.share {
position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-filter: url("#goo");
  filter: url('http://www.martmars.com/index.html#goo');
  position: relative;
}
```

I don't understand why ? (i try with url like "http://www..." and works with chrome but no with firefox online)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

I find something after try a lot.
If a do :

```
.share {
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-filter: url("#goo");
  filter: url('../toto.html#goo');
  position: relative;
}
```

It's wroks well in any browser. But does'nt work if is in Index.html.
I don't know why.
But it's works well, every where whith that :

```
.share {
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-filter: url("#goo");
  filter: url('../#goo');
  position: relative;
}
```

Voila :)

Comment: Sorry about my English